Neural network with just one Dense layer
I have a model which works well with just one Dense layer. My model has an input layer, a Dense layer, and then one Reshape layer, which reshapes the output into the desired form. Normally, neural network models consist of one or more hidden layers and then one output layer. My model's performance certainly improves if I add another Dense layer, and then I can say that my model has one hidden layer and one output layer.
But in the case where it has only one Dense layer, should that layer be considered a hidden layer or an output layer?

In general, if it’s between the input and the output layers, it is hidden. they are either interfacial or hidden.

@EngrStudent, thanks for the comment. Can you explain what interfacial means here?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

@ryan1 - interfacial is "of or pertaining to interfaces".  The parts that connect with other parts, the boundaries.  Input and output layers are interfacial layers.
